# Nestjs rabbitmq AMQP connection is not available

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

Using @golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq I tried the connection manager to not wait for a connection.

Here's how I use it

```
# app.module.ts
...

import RabbitModule from '@/modules/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.module'
@Module({
  imports: [..., RabbitModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: []
})
export default class AppModule {}
```

```
# modules\rabbitmq\rabbitmq.module.ts
...


@Module({
  imports: [RabbitMQConf, RabbitMQMessagingModule],
  providers: [RabbitmqService],
  controllers: [RabbitmqController],
  exports: [RabbitmqService]
})
export default class RabbitMQMessagingModule {}
```

```
# configs\rabbitmq.ts
...


@Module({
  imports: [RabbitMQConf, RabbitMQMessagingModule],
  providers: [RabbitmqService],
  controllers: [RabbitmqController],
  exports: [RabbitmqService]
})
export default class RabbitMQMessagingModule {}
```

```
# modules\rabbitmq\rabbitmq.service.ts
...

@Injectable()
export default class RabbitmqService {
  constructor(private readonly amqpConnection: AmqpConnection) {} // other module services if needs to be injected
...
  public publish(): void {
    this.amqpConnection.publish('amq.fanout', 'amq_fanout_queue_iot', { msg: 'hello world' })
  }
}
```

```
# modules\rabbitmq\rabbitmq.controller.ts
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common'

import Unbanning from '@/decorators/unbanning.decorator'

import RabbitmqService from './rabbitmq.service'
@Controller('amqp')
export default class RabbitmqController {
  constructor(private readonly amqp: RabbitmqService) {}
  @Unbanning()
  @Get('sending')
  send() {
    return this.amqp.publish()
  }
```

When I went to visit `http://localhost:3030/api/v1/amqp/sending` access the request.The result is the following error.

```
[ exception ]-26 Error: AMQP connection is not available
    at AmqpConnection.publish (F:\nestjs\node_modules\.pnpm\@golevelup+nestjs-rabbitmq@3.6.1_@nestjs+common@9.4.2_rxjs@7.8.1\node_modules\@golevelup\nestjs-rabbitmq\src\amqp\connection.ts:544:13)
    at RabbitmqService.publish (F:\nestjs\src\modules\rabbitmq\rabbitmq.service.ts:58:25)
    at RabbitmqController.send (F:\nestjs\src\modules\rabbitmq\rabbitmq.controller.ts:22:22)
    at 

...
```

Ask your brothers, what should I do.
Wait on the line. Thank you!!!

Who can help me solve the problem